# No Products Showing Anywhere On Site

Tags: products

I am pulling my hair out trying to get to the bottom of this fault. I have read various sites and solutions but nothing has worked. I have tried the following solutions from different sites and they are all correct - still no products display anywhere on site, Categories will display with info and featured image but no products etc.

The products must be Visible in Catalog.
The products must be Enabled.
Product must have a stock Quantity.
The product must be set to In Stock.
If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
The product must be assigned to the target Category.
If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
You must refresh your Cache / Indices, just to make sure.

I hope someone can help

Comment: Can you see any products when going to www.yoursite.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/product/? I know you are using a custom theme (from a previous answer). If you change your theme to the default theme, flush cache, reindex, do you see products on the default theme?

Comment: Have you enabled and checked your logs? I've have an error in the catalog/product/list.phtml that may prevent products from displaying. Try changing to the default theme and see if that returns products. Are you using multi store mode? If so make sure the correct store code is being set.

Comment: I just checked the link you sent and all the products are display in list format yeh.

Comment: If I go to System > Design. The Current Package name is set to Default already.

Comment: Is it base/default or default/default? On a previous question, you said you were using a custom theme

Comment: Did you solve your issue with no products displaying frontend after upgrade.I am facing the same issue please suggest if you have solved it? Thank you

Comment: are you using flat catalog for products/categories?